Best way to address this Whirlpool Home Filtration Leak
I have this of water filtration setup in my house. It was like this when I bought the house and a couple of plumbers have told me it's weird.
https://imgur.com/a/FBX0off
I noticed yesterday that the filter closest to the water heater was leaking. I replaced the o ring and the filter, and cleaned the canister threads. When I put it back together, I realized it's leaking under the cap, so it seems to be coming from the housing itself, so I think I will have to replace that piece.
It looks like this model WHKF-DWHV has been updated by Whirlpool.
So I guess I have three questions:

Do I actually need this double filter setup?

Can I replace the leaking filter with the updated model and leave the other one alone?

In the meantime, could I just turn this filter to the off position so it stops dripping?



Just replace the setup with the updated model.
You can turn it to the off position and you will get unfiltered water until you replace it.  It is not going to damage anything.
